# jQuery Post not working after upgrading to MVC5, but jQuery AJAX works fine

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm attempting to upgrade a project from .NET 4 & MVC4 to .NET 4.5 & MVC5. I've managed to get everything working fine except for my jQuery.post() methods.

I've created a simple test API controller:

```
public class HomeApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string Test(TestObject test)
    {
        return test.name + "asdf";
    }
    public class TestObject
    {
        public string name;
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to get the following $.post() working. This is exactly how I did it in MVC4 and it worked fine.

```
var data = { name: 'owen' };
$.post('/api/HomeApi/Test/', data)
.done(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

But the name always comes through as null and I just get "asdf" as the result. I've also tried JSON.stringify(data).

But if I use $.ajax() like this, it works fine and I get "owenasdf" as the result.

```
var data = { name: 'owen' };
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/HomeApi/Test/",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("An error has occured!!!");
    }
});
```

I've spent half a day looking through google and all I can find is examples of $.ajax(), and I really don't want to have to go through all my old code and change $.post() to $.ajax(). $.post() is so much easier!

Can someone tell me why $.post() is no longer working?

UPDATE

When I inspect the posts in fiddler, these are the differences:

POST (using JSON.stringify() and without, same result)

```
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

AJAX

```
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: Does `$.post()` send the correct `content-type` header? Can you inspect the post with Fiddler?

Comment: In the ajax you stringify...the post does not

Comment: @DavidG I've updated my question with fiddler results.

Comment: @tymeJV I've tried with stringify and without (as noted in the question). And I never used JSON.stringify() in MVC4.

Comment: But the content-type is being sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `JSON`.

Comment: That's the content-type I used in MVC4 and it worked. How do I tell $.post() to send as application/json? Or is there a setting somewhere that tells my ApiControllers to accept application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your TestObject class you have declared "name" as variable, it should be Property.

```
    public class TestObject
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```